# delaying the hover of background- image

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: block;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 70px;
  background: url('img/logo_orig.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  background: url('img/logo_hov.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

This creates a button with a background image, when hovered it hnages the background.

I want to add a delay to the background image when hovered. similar to using

```
transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
```

Comment: `background-image` is not an animatable property (yet). You may need to rethink here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this.

HTML:

```css
#cf {
  position: relative;
  height: 281px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#cf img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  height:inherit;
  width:inherit;
}
#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="http://cdp.pasctunisie.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/light-circles-wave-powerpoint-backgrounds.jpg" />
</div>
```